# Redux has an array but cannot map the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My redux state has the 3 users I requested, but I cannot map it when finally calling it on the component.

[image: redux state]

But I can't map it on a table. I don't know why.

```
const EditUser = ({ history }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userList = useSelector(state => state.userList);
  const { error, users } = userList;

  const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo && userInfo.isAdmin) {
      dispatch(listUsers());
    } else {
      history.push('/login');
    }
  }, [dispatch, history, userInfo]);
  return (
    <Box>
      <Box></Box>
      <Table variant="striped">
        <Thead>
          <Tr>
            <Th>ID</Th>
            <Th>Name</Th>
            <Th>E-Mail</Th>
            <Th>Admin</Th>
            <Th></Th>
          </Tr>
        </Thead>
        <Tbody>
          {users.map(user => (
            <Tr key={user.id}>
              <Td>{user._id}</Td>
              <Td>{user.name}</Td>
              <Td>{user.email}</Td>
              <Td>{user.isAdmin ? <CheckIcon /> : <CloseIcon />}</Td>
              <Td>
                <Link>
                  <EditIcon />
                </Link>
              </Td>
            </Tr>
          ))}
        </Tbody>
      </Table>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

This is my userList Component and it gives me the error of 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' even tho I have an array of users.

Comment: Can you post the array returned please ?

Comment: ` users[
  {
    "isAdmin": true,
    "_id": "607e9b8ee1723d374465031c",
    "name": "Admin User",
    "email": "admin@example.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$UHReqta4/iVrW7gmS.dxhuaCOU2dYAi..cZ8FwkggR6f7FzDoIDVG",
    "__v": 0,
    "createdAt": "2021-04-20T09:14:54.969Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-04-20T09:14:54.969Z"
  },
`
This and  2 other users have been returned inside the redux state but I can't seem to call it out on the component, I tried to console.log(users) but it returns undefined don't know why.

Comment: Can you read other values from the store beside the array in the same component?

Comment: I would add a check here: {users?.map(...)}

And to make your code a bit cleaner: 

const { loading, users, error } = useSelector(state => ({
        loading: state.userList.loading,
        users: state.userList.users,
        error: state.userList.error
    }))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux state takes a couple of seconds to load.

try adding condition before mapping the array if there are users or not.

```
<Tbody>
          {users && users.map(user => (
            <Tr key={user.id}>
              <Td>{user._id}</Td>
              <Td>{user.name}</Td>
              <Td>{user.email}</Td>
              <Td>{user.isAdmin ? <CheckIcon /> : <CloseIcon />}</Td>
              <Td>
                <Link>
                  <EditIcon />
                </Link>
              </Td>
            </Tr>
          ))}
        </Tbody>
```